# Speed performance rewriting array in for loop

Tags: python, performance, numpy, optimization

I have a 2D data set with `shape = (500, 500)`. From a given location `(x_0, y_0)` I want to map the distance for each element/pixel to that given location. I do this by determining all the unique distances from `(x_0, y_0)` and map them using integers. Such a map for a `6 x 6` data set looks like this:

```
[9 8 7 6 7 8]
[8 5 4 3 4 5]
[7 4 2 1 2 4]
[6 3 1 0 1 3]
[7 4 2 1 2 4]
[8 5 4 3 4 5]
```

where the integers correspond to the unique distances stored in the following array:

```
[0.  1.  1.41421356  2.  2.23606798  2.82842712  3.  3.16227766  3.60555128  4.24264069]
```

The code that determines these distances is the following:

```
def func(data, (x_0,y_0)):
  y, x = numpy.indices((data.shape))
  r = numpy.sqrt((x - x_0)**2 + (y - y_0)**2)

  float_values = numpy.unique(r.ravel())  # Unique already sorts the result 
  int_values = numpy.arange(float_values.shape[0]).astype(numpy.int) 

  for idx in range(float_values.shape[0])[::-1]:
    r[r == float_values[idx]] = int_values[idx] 

  return float_values, r
```

The `for` loop is a bottleneck. It takes too long for the application I need. Is there a way to speed it up/increase its performance? Or is there perhaps a complete different but faster method of getting the output I require?

Comment: Do you really need the whole indexing scheme, or would you be OK with just storing the actual distances. Sure you'd sacrifice a bit of space, but who really cares?

Comment: Alternatively, would you be willing to compute a (symmetrical) 999x999 array with zero in the center, and just index into that?

Comment: Also, [`np.unique`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) has a `return_inverse` argument that you can use to just get the indices directly. But `unique` is an expensive operation you should try to avoid doing if you can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a vectorized approach making use of `masking` -

```
def func_mask_vectorized(data, (x_0, y_0)):
    # Leverage broadcasting with open meshes to create the squared distances/ids
    m,n = data.shape
    Y,X = np.ogrid[:m,:n]
    ids = (X-x_0)**2 + (Y-y_0)**2

    # Setup mask that will help us retrieve the unique "compressed" IDs
    # (similar to what return_inverse does).
    # This is done by setting 1s at ids places and then using that mask to 
    # assign range covered array, in effect setting up the unique compress. IDs.
    mask = np.zeros(ids.max()+1, dtype=bool)
    mask[ids] = 1    
    id_arr = mask.astype(int)
    id_arr[mask] = np.arange(mask.sum())
    r_out = id_arr[ids]

    # Finally extract out the unique ones among the IDs & get their sqrt values
    float_values_out = np.sqrt(np.flatnonzero(mask))
    return float_values_out, r_out
```

#### Benchmarking

Timing on the proposed setup with a data of shape `(500,500)`, using the numbers range of `0-9` as also used in the sample from the question and timing all the complete solutions in this section below -

```
In [371]: np.random.seed(0)
     ...: data = np.random.randint(0,10,(500,500))
     ...: x_0 = 2
     ...: y_0 = 3

# Original soln
In [372]: %timeit func(data, (x_0,y_0))
1 loop, best of 3: 6.77 s per loop

# @Daniel's soln
In [373]: %timeit func_return_inverse(data, (x_0,y_0))
10 loops, best of 3: 23.9 ms per loop

# Soln from this post
In [374]: %timeit func_mask_vectorized(data, (x_0,y_0))
100 loops, best of 3: 5.02 ms per loop
```

Extending for cases where the numbers may extend to `100` or even `1000` doesn't change much on how these stack up -

```
In [397]: np.random.seed(0)
     ...: data = np.random.randint(0,100,(500,500))
     ...: x_0 = 50
     ...: y_0 = 50

In [398]: %timeit func(data, (x_0,y_0))
     ...: %timeit func_return_inverse(data, (x_0,y_0))
     ...: %timeit func_mask_vectorized(data, (x_0,y_0))
1 loop, best of 3: 5.62 s per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 20.7 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 4.28 ms per loop

In [399]: np.random.seed(0)
     ...: data = np.random.randint(0,1000,(500,500))
     ...: x_0 = 500
     ...: y_0 = 500

In [400]: %timeit func(data, (x_0,y_0))
     ...: %timeit func_return_inverse(data, (x_0,y_0))
     ...: %timeit func_mask_vectorized(data, (x_0,y_0))
1 loop, best of 3: 6.87 s per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 21.9 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 5.05 ms per loop
```

Comment: Great as always @Divakar. Yet, would you mind to also state the quantitative performance comparison data? Say using **`from zmq import Stopwatch; aClk = Stopwatch()`** and framing each  **C**ode**U**nder**T**est snippet with the said **`data`** size like this: `aClk.start(); func_mask_vectorised(...); aClk.stop()` this will get **`[us]`**-exact clocking of the performance to compare apples to apples. That's fair, isn't it?

Comment: @user3666197 Check out the timing section. Hope that looks fair. I have used IPython timing tool - `%timeit`, as that's easier and pretty accurate.

Comment: Great, as always. Yes, on having a systematically ~ 4x faster execution `[us]`-exact clocking resolution does not matter to measure more than a winning nose distance :o)  All the best, Sir.

Answer (score 1):

1. Don't mess around with your "unique distances" array.  Just pre-compute the distances, indexed by the radicand (sum of squares).  This is simply

   roots = [sqrt(float(i)) for i in range(upper_limit)]
2. Then, since the pixels are contiguous, you have the option of looping from your reference point outward, simply mapping the entire applicable slice of `roots`, from the reference point to the edge of the matrix.

Alternately, quit looping at all: let `numpy`'s vectorized operations do it for you, such as

```
dist = np.sqrt(dist_matrix)
```

Comment: Would you mind to post a speedup factor ( as detailed in comment under Divakar's vectorised code ) of your code-proposal against the orginal code? That permits to compare apples to apples & that's fair, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `return_inverse`-parameter of `unique`:

```
def func(data, (x_0,y_0)):
    y, x = numpy.indices(data.shape)
    r = (x - x_0)**2 + (y - y_0)**2
    float_values, r = numpy.unique(r, return_inverse=True)
    return float_values ** 0.5, r.reshape(data.shape)
```

Comment: Would you mind to post a speedup factor ( as detailed in comment under Divakar's vectorised code ) of your code-proposal against the orginal code? That permits to compare apples to apples & that's fair, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

It seams that your indexing scheme (integers in the data) will be in the same order as the distances.  If that is always the case, the array of distances can be produced without the actual content of the data.

I'm basing this solution on an index calculation that uses the x and y pixel offsets of each position to the anchor position.  Assuming "so" is the smallest offset and "ho" is the larger one with "mo" being the maximum possible offset in either direction:

index = ho + (mo+1) * lo - lo * (lo+1) // 2

To compute the distances in the array, we only need to know the dimensions of the matrix and the position of the anchor pixel.

```
import numpy as np
def distanceArray(x,y,cols,rows):
    maxDx  = max(x,cols-x)
    maxDy  = max(y,rows-y)
    maxD   = max(maxDx,maxDy)
    minD   = min(maxDx,maxDy)
    lo = np.arange(minD)[:,None]
    hi = np.arange(maxD)
    sqs = lo*lo + hi*hi
    unique = np.tri(*sqs.shape,maxD-minD, dtype=bool)[::-1,::-1]
    return np.sqrt(sqs[unique])
```

If we only focus on pixel offsets from the anchor position, we will get a range of horizontal and vertical detlas that is determined by the bounds of the data's shape (maxDx and maxDy).

For the distance calculations we can ignore the vertical/horizontal directions and create a small and a large(r) range. (lo and hi from maxD and minD)

To compute all the sum of squares, we can transpose one of the two ranges into a vertical vector (lo) and then add it to the other one (hi) after squaring their values (hi * hi + lo * lo).  This yields a 2D matrix with all combinations of square sums (sqs).

Out of that matrix the top triangle is a duplication of its counterpart.  So we mask out the duplicate distance pairs using a triangular boolean matrix.  (unique)  Masking the top triangle will ensure that the order of the square sums that come out of the masking operation are in the appropriate order.

Finally, the filtered sqs values contain exactly what we need, and in the right order.  We can apply the costly square root function to only that final result.

Not applying the distance calculation to every pixel should allow some significant performance gains as it will allow you to use the indexed distances only when needed.  I guess it would be unfair to compare the performance of this distanceArray function with the other solutions (as it only does part of what they do) but, given that not having to do something is also part of optimization, the end result will likely be better (by a factor of about 5x that of Divakar in my non-scientific testing).

Note that if you only use the distances for a small subset of the pixels, you may want to avoid all these calculations and use a dictionary as a cache to compute the distances "on demand" based on the dX and dY offsets (keyed on and ordered tuple).  This will perform the absolute minimum number of calculations and will only compute the distance once for any particular offset pair.  You can even continue using that cache for other anchor positions and data shapes since the offset pairs will always produce the same distance no matter position of the anchor.

[EDIT] to obtain the same indexing as I used for distanceArray, you could use this:

```
def offsets(x,y,cols,rows):
    mo   = max(x,cols-x-1,y,rows-y-1)+1

    dx   = abs(np.arange(cols)-x)
    dy   = abs(np.arange(rows)-y)[:,None]

    mo21 = 2 * mo - 1
    ly = dy*(mo21 - dy )//2  # mo*lo - lo*(lo+1)//2 when dy is lowest
    lx = dx*(mo21 - dx )//2  # mo*lo - lo*(lo+1)//2 when dx is lowest

    return np.maximum(dx,dy) + np.minimum(lx,ly)

offsets(3,3,6,6)

array([[9, 8, 6, 3, 6, 8],
       [8, 7, 5, 2, 5, 7],
       [6, 5, 4, 1, 4, 5],
       [3, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2],
       [6, 5, 4, 1, 4, 5],
       [8, 7, 5, 2, 5, 7]])
```